# How to set up chrome.storage.managed

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

### Firefox

MDN has clear instructions about how to use `browser.storage.managed` ([storage.managed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed), [Managed storage manifests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests#managed_storage_manifests)).

- Create a JSON named the same as the extension ID
- Place the JSON according to [Manifest location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests#manifest_location)
- Set the JSON properties

  - "name": the same as the extension ID
  - "data": the storage object data

```json
{
  "name": "extension-id",
  "description": "ignored",
  "type": "storage",
  "data": {
    "colour": "management thinks it should be blue!"
  }
}
```

### Chrome

Chrome [storage.managed](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage#property-managed) instructions are limited.

- What should the filename be?
- Where should it be place?

  - On Linux, one place has been said to be `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/`
- What should the format of the JSON be?
- What would be the ID used to identify the correct extension?

Comment: @wOxxOm "schema.json" is not a major problem. The problem is the format and location of the actual data JSON.

Comment: Ah! The article says it's the same as Chrome's [own policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/). That site describes the exact locations for each platform, there's also a dedicated "Configuring Apps and Extensions by Policy" section.